# Linear Interpolation speed : Numpy vs Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation

I have a 1d-lookup table of 100 rows. each y value corresponds to x value and I want to do interpolation between values of x data which are 0 decimal places so they are natural numbers basically. I want to achieve something like this

```
y = [1,2,3,4,.....100]
x = [2.1124 , 2.3243 ,2.3412 , 2.3423 , .... 3.5980]

Whats value of y = 1.2 ? , 1.8  , 4.5 ?
```

I am stuck between three options because of speed issues :

1- I use linear piecewise interpolation first to get all possible 1 decimal place vlaues between 1 to 100 so the table will be of 1000 rows then. I store this in a numpy array in the code and query a value within this array when needed.

2- I use pandas library and call this .csv file which has got these 1000 rows of data and everytime get the value from there.

3- or I create a interpolation function that will do the linear interp in the asked range using scipy library . for eg if x value is 2.3415 then the function will automatically interpolate between y = 4 and 5 as this x value (2.3415) is in the nearest range of these y values

which method will be faster to execute, I am going to use this feature in a code that will run live (continously)

Answer (score 0):

**Speaking about peformance:** Yes, lookup from pre-calculated table in memory is very fast, usually faster than doing the calculation live. So yes, if it is an option to pre-calculate all possible values and keeping them in memory is beneficial, if you access these values lots of times, which outweighs the time to pre-calculate. But, you need to be sure that you are never looking for a non-precalculated value, and that you don't run into memory issues (if you need to buffer not 1000 but 100,000,000 values)

**Speaking about building something that works:** As per your own example, I am pretty sure your pre-calculation approach won't work at all! Precalculating to 1st decimal, so expanding memory from 100 to 1000 records, would not allow you to find `2.3415` - `2.3415` will not show up as per your explanation:

- If you pre-calculate the linearly interpolated 10 values on 1 additional decimal, so on O(1e-5) between `2.3412` and `2.3423`, you will see `2.34120`, `2.34121`, `2.34122`, ..., which is not what you need.
- Also if you reamin on O(1e-4) precision (so you add `2.3412`, `2.3413`, ...) this approach fails if 2 neighboring numbers have a distance of >1e-4, which would require you to add more than 10 new figures in between, so the 100 -> 1000 math does not work

Overall: Pre-calculate only if you are 100% sure that all needed values will be in the lookup - and only if you access these values really, really often. Often the best approach for interpolation would be 1 single vector operation, so get all of you `x_i` in a single matrix, and interpolate them all with a single matrix-vector operation. That will do exactly what you need, and applies to all values at once - faster than any form of pre-calculation or `for` loop

Comment: 1- yes I am sure I will not need anyvalue other than the pre-calculation method. so my goal is to convert x-axis values which are currently 0 dec places to 1 decimal place ones . so between 1 and 2 , I want to break it down to 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4...1.9.2  
in this process ,  I would get corresponding y-axis values too 

2- my main goal here is speed in real runtime of code , if using a 1000 row numpy array does the job then I am happy with it .

Comment: also can you please explain a bit more ( maybe in code structure) about the single vector operation you mentioned in the end. 

here's what I need :
1- my code will read sensor value that I will round to 4 decimal places , I will then go to y-axis data and see what is the value closest to it .

2- based on this y-value I would like to perform interpolation between the closest x-axis values so I can display that newly interp x-value on console

please show a code like structure if possible :D